# Airplay from iPhone to Airport Express, but use iPhone LTE

Tags: airplay

is there a way to stream content (music) to an Airport Express from an iPhone, but using that iPhone’s LTE data instead of the WiFi connection for internet?

Basically the LTE is a ton faster than our WiFi. I don’t need the Airport Express for anything but music streaming to a set of speakers. A natural way of doing that would be to open a personal hotspot on the iPhone, and connecting the AE to that - unfortunately the iPhone hotspot does not show up as a network in Airport Utility; it seems making a direct connection isn’t possible. Is there another option?

edit: think I figured it out. Disconnected the AE from LAN, but it’s still in “Create a wireless network” mode. When connecting to that WiFi from iPhone, it will show up with a “No Internet Connection” warning on iOS, and the iPhone falls back to cellular..

however, the connection keeps dropping out and reconnecting. Airplay keeps glitching out / there is intermittent silence a few times per minute. Seems like either the iPhone or the AE or both don’t like this connection. Quite annoying!

Comment: What does LTE or your Internet speeds have to do with streaming from an iPhone to an Airport?  Is your AE connected to the LAN so you can turn off Wireless and still configure it?  You don't **need** WiFi to use AirPlay.

Comment: ok just imagine there is no home internet/WiFi. I have an Airport Express connected to some speakers, and an iPhone, and no other device. I want to stream music from iPhone to AE. I want to use the iPhone’s LTE.